# Sigma algebra respect to random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $X(\omega)=\omega \mod 2$, which is a random variable.
Then, my first question is, what is $\sigma(X)$?
In my understanding, 
$\sigma(X)=\{\{\omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\}\mid B\subset R\}$, so $\sigma(X)=\{\emptyset,\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\},\Omega\}$.

Let $Y(\omega)=1_{\omega\geq 4}$. 
Then, my second question is, what is $\sigma(X,Y)$?
In my thought, $\sigma(X,Y)=\{\{\omega\mid (X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in B_1\times B_2\}\mid B_1,B_2\subseteq R\}$. 
$\sigma(X,Y)=\left\{\{2\},\{5\},\{1,3\},\{4,6\},\{2,5\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,4,6\},\{1,3,5\},\{4,5,6\},\{1,3,4,6\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{2,4,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4,6\},\{1,3,4,5,6\},\Omega\right\}$
Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

I don't beleive you've identified $\ \sigma\left(X\right)\ $ correctly.  Consider your expression, $\ X^{-1}\left(B\right) = \{\omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\}\ $, for the elements of $\ \sigma\left(X\right)\ $.  This is correct.  Strictly speaking, $\ B\ $ should be restricted to be a *measurable* subset of $\ R\ $, but in this case it makes no difference if you take all subsets of $\ R\ $ to be measurable.

Since the only possible values of $\ X\left(\omega\right)\ $ are $\ 0\ $ and $\ 1\ $, then unless $\ 0\in B\ $ or  $\ 1\in B\ $, we must have $\ X^{-1}\left(B\right) = \emptyset\ $. If $\ 0\in B\ $ but $\ 1\not\in B\ $, then $\ X\left(\omega\right)\in B\ $ if and only if $\ \omega= 2, 4, \mbox{ or }\ 6\ $, so $\ X^{-1}\left(B\right) = \left\{2,4,6\right\}\ $. Similarly, if $\ 1\in B\ $ but $\ 0\not\in B\ $, then $\ X^{-1}\left(B\right) = \left\{1,3,5\right\}\ $, and if both $\ 0\in B\ $ and $\ 1\not\in B\ $, then $\ X^{-1}\left(B\right) = \left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}= \Omega\ $, thus giving $\sigma(X)=\{\emptyset,\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6\},\Omega\}$.

Your definition of $\ \sigma\left(X,Y\right)\ $ is also not quite correct. It should be
\begin{align}
\sigma(X&,Y)=\\
&\{\{\omega\mid (X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in B \}\mid B\subseteq R\times R, \mbox{measurable}\}\ .
\end{align}That is, the elements of $\ \sigma(X,Y)\ $ are the inverse images not merely of *product* sets, but *all measurable* subsets of $\ R\times R\ $.  Nevertheless, your list of sets in $\ \sigma(X,Y)\ $ is *nearly* right. You've inadvertently omitted the empty set from the list

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct answer as explained in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4712814/1239177 . For example, if consider only (0,0), I believe the pre-image should only be {2}

Comment: Yes, you're right. It looks like I must have suffered some sort of brain fade when answering the second question. Thank you for picking the error up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
The definition of $\sigma(X,Y)$ is 
$$\{\{(\omega_1,\omega_2)\mid (X(\omega_1),Y(\omega_2))\in B\}\mid B\subseteq R\times R, mesurable\}$$,
and 
for the case $(0,1)\in B$ and others not in $B$, 
$$\{(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)\}$$.
I need to consider $2^4$ cases, like $(0,0)\in B$, $(0,1)\in B$, $(1,0)\notin B$, $(1,1)\in B$...,  right?

Comment: Yes. Although it's simpler to just do the 4 cases: $1. \ (0,0) \in B, (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\notin B\ $;  $2.\ (0,1) \in B, (0,0), (1,0), (1,1)\notin B\ $; $3. \ (1,0) \in B, (0,0), (0,1), (1,1)\notin B\ $; and $4.\ (1,1) \in B, (0,0), (0,1),(1,0) \notin B\ $.   The sets in $\ \sigma(X)\ $ are then just all the unions (including the empty union) of those you get from these four cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer.